# TERM=(linux|xterm) vi in an xterm or the AAABBBBBBCCDDD-problem

Tags: vim, console, xterm, key-mapping

Usually when I want to run `vim` in a desktop `konsole` session, I make sure the TERM variable is set to `linux` as the arrow keys don't work in insert mode with `TERM=xterm`. They show capital A..D instead of moving the cursor.

Now I think this is the wrong way of doing thingsas `konsole` or `xterm` is actually of type `xterm`.

Is there a better way for making arrow keys work under `vi` / `vim`?

OS: Kubuntu 13.04 (Clean install)

Comment: Are you sure you've not changed the default _Key bindings_ in the _current profile_?

Comment: Clean install on Ubuntu.

Comment: That's trying to use the arrow keys in insert mode without having done `set nocp`, right?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Insert mode and *before* I do `set nocp`, yes.

Comment: maybe worth an answer ...

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Here is an interensting find: `ls -l /etc/alternatives/vi` which outputs `/usr/bin/vim.tiny` which in turn explains a lot of the strange behaviour. I solved it with `sudo update-alternatives --config vi`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I know what's going on.

You've not configured `vim` to disable `vi` compatibility mode.

In `vi`, you can only press the arrow keys in *command* mode. When in insert mode, the character sequences sent upon pressing the arrow keys are treated as if the characters were entered individually.

Now, upon startup, `vi` sets the terminal in *keypad transmit mode* (kx). In that mode, the terminals usually send a different character sequence upon pressing the arrow keys than when not.

For instance, the <kbd>Up</kbd> key sends `\eOA` in kx mode and `\e[A` when not.

To set the terminal in kx mode, it looks up the `smkx` (Set Mode Keypad Transmit) capability in the terminfo database for the current value of `$TERM`.

If you look at the `smkx` capability for `xterm`, `konsole` and `linux`, you see:

```
$ infocmp -1 linux | grep smkx
$ infocmp -1 xterm | grep smkx
    smkx=\E[?1h\E=,
$ infocmp -1 konsole | grep smkx
    smkx=\E[?1h\E=,
```

That is `smkx` is not defined in the `linux` entry.

What that means is that when you start `vim` with `TERM=linux`, vim doesn't set the terminal in kx mode, that means it sends `\e[A` instead of `\eOA` when you press the <kbd>Up</kbd> key for instance.

Now, what does `\eOA` do in vim when you're in insert mode? `\e` (ESC), leaves insert mode and returns to command mode. `O` opens a new line and enters insert mode again, `A` inserts the `A` character.

While `\e[A`, `\e` (ESC) leaves insert mode, `[A` is an unknown combination (in `vim`, `[` is a prefix and is always followed by another character), so does nothing.

So what you need to do is: keep `$TERM` as it is, don't use arrow keys in insert mode when in vi compatibility or add a `set nocp` to your `~/.vimrc` so you can use arrow keys in insert mode.

Comment: Yeah I figured out the "don't use arrow keys in insert mode when in vi compatibility"-option myself, but I didn't like that ;o)

Answer (score -2):

The fast way to fix this is:

```
echo "set nocp" > ~/.vimrc
```

This should fix it :)

Comment: You should improve your answer and include why this solves the problem.